# Publish code in git repository assembla as new branch

Tags: macos, git, svn

I have an iphone project which I need to publish in assembla git repository as a new branch.My Lead has given me the access to the account. I am using mac os x . Please help me out.

Comment: Would you like to know the command line way or the graphical way?

Comment: @ohope5: graphical way..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a GUI git application. I use SourceTree, and I would recommend this. Get it [HERE](http://sourcetreeapp.com/).

Then you need to add the assembla repository. Open SourceTree and click the add repository button (top left corner).

Open assembla in your browser, log in and then go to your profile and click manage ssh keys. Add yours by pasting the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. If this does not exist, then create a key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` first.

Now open the specific repo and copy the git URL to clipboard. Back in SourceTree copy this as the URL and then fill in the destination folder and click clone. Now you have a local copy!

Now open the new repo in SourceTree and click "Branch" fill in all the fields as necessary. Now, put all the necessary files in this branch, click "commit" and then click "push". Now you should successfully have added a working branch to the online repo with your code.

A small word though, if your are going to be using git a lot in the future I would recommend learning how to use it on the command line, even if you still prefer to use a GUI app it would still be helpful and a useful thing to do.